# apache ignite configure a custom cache store

Tags: java, configuration, ignite

I am creating my own custom ignite `org.apache.ignite.cache.store.CacheStore` implementation to persist a cache to MongoDB. I understand how to specify my new custom cache class in the ignite XML:

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                ... 
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
                        <constructor-arg value="com.glib.ws.ignite.MyCustomMongoCacheStore"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                ... 
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Is there a way to specify/supply some properties to the instance of `com.glib.ws.ignite.MyCustomMongoCacheStore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your own `com.glib.ws.ignite.MyCustomMongoCacheStoreFactory` `implements Factory, Serializable`, which will accept all of these properties, construct your actual `MyCustomMongoCacheStore` with these properties.